# How to keep vbNewLine when passing a string from Access to Outlook mail?

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I have a string that contains vbNewLine positions.

For example :

```vb
Dim strSalesOrderRemarksas string

strSalesOrderRemarks= "Hello" & vbNewLine 
strSalesOrderRemarks= strExample & "World"
```

When I debug via Access I see:

> Hello
> World

Then I pass this string to an Outlook mail object.
I have a mail template that contains a body with text, in this text there is a string like this {strBody}.

Then, when I want to replace this part with the strExample it gets shown in the mail without the vbNewLine. So the output in the mail is: helloworld

This was the actual line of code

```
.HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "{strBody}", strSalesOrderRemarks)
```

I looked at similar problems, most of them containing info about replacing a vbNewLine.

Comment: To use HTML, replace the new line character with a `"<br>"` string.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it should be : Thanks to Brax

```
    strSalesOrderRemarks = Replace(strSalesOrderRemarks, vbNewLine, "<br>")
    '
    .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "{strBody}", strSalesOrderRemarks)
```